# Faster calculation of multiple matrices' eigenvalues & eigenvectors

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numba

I have several thousands of 3x3 matrices, which are stored as a numpy array Nx9, where N is a number of matrices, stored in rows. I want to calculate the eigenvalues & eigenvectors for each of them (i.e. `e, v = np.linalg.eig(matrices[row_idx, :].reshape((3, 3))`, applied to each `row_idx` in `range(matrices.shape[0])`).

So, the function would look as:

```
def compute_eigen(matrices):
    e_list, v_list = [], []
    for i in range(matrices.shape[0]):
        e, v = np.linalg.eig(matrices[row_idx, :].reshape((3, 3))
        v = -v
        e_list.append(e)
        v_list.append(v)
    return e_list, v_list
```

Now, how to make this run really fast? `np.apply_along_axis` is just a syntactic sugar for the for-loops, apparently, so it did not help much.

I tried to look into Numba, and run the same function with `@jit(nopython=True)` decorator, which, indeed, dropped the execution time of this function from ~20s to ~2s for ~6000 matrices. However, is it possible to drop it under 1s? Is there some smart way to do it (assuming no usage of some very powerful hardware, GPUs etc)? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need the loop, `e, v = np.linalg.eig(matrices.reshape((-1,3, 3))` works fine

Comment: @Brenlla thanks! It was not clear to me from the `np.linalg.eig` function documentation, to be honest.